# Applying settings on prettyPhoto open public function

Tags: jquery

I want to make a div by:

```
$.prettyPhoto.open('images/fullscreen/image.jpg','Title','Description');
```

and add the `modal: true`, and hide the close button.

How can I do that with the `$.prettyPhoto.open` public function?

[**prettyPhoto documentation**](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Can you clarify more the exact behavior you need.
2- Can you tell if you are now able to use PrettyPhoto in it's normal usage scenario or that it's not even working with you.

I can get you a solution, but just confirm the current situation and tell what you can do right now.

and if it's possible, tell what is the final outcome that you need, maybe the solution is simple.

**Update:** *as a result to your recent comment*

You can easily trigger actions on page load to Simulate a user click and so chieve the same scenario with the normal usage of prettyPhoto. (hooking to events)
consider this code block:

`$(function ()
{
$('#MyAnchorID').click();
});`

this will trigger the anchor click event on the page load as if the user clicked the anchor.

here is [a sample code that you can check](http://jsfiddle.net/cMrC8/4/) :

Regarding your second problem to open prettyPhoto as modal and not to show the close button, you will need to modify the internal CSS that is shipped with the Prettyphoto plugin:

1- Open `prettyPhoto.CSS` file

2- Search for `a.pp_close`, this is the class that renders the close button.

3- you will find it like this:

```
a.pp_close {
            display: block;
            float: right;
            line-height:22px;
            text-indent: -10000px;
        }
```

3- Change the `display` value from `block` to `none` to avoid showing the close button inside your modal.

4- that's it, let me know if it work.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i want it load in page load but with option

Comment: is it a must to use the public function?
Cause I made it to work using the normal usage (for example: jquery to handle click event) , and to pass the options just like you wanted

Comment: click? no i want it open in page load

Comment: the same problem i cant not use the normail as this $("a[rel^='pretty']").prettyPhoto();

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize prettyphoto with custom parameters *without* launching a popup, then launch the popup using the public API:

```
$().prettyPhoto({modals: 'true', param2: 'foo', param3: 'bar'});
$('a.class').click(
    function () {
        $.prettyPhoto.open('http://URL?iframe=true&width=500&height=90%', 'Title','Description');
        return false;
    });
```

To hide the 'close' button, you could either set new modal markup through the 'markup' parameter (copy the default markup and *exclude* `<a class="pp_close" href="#">Close</a>` from the code) or you could use CSS such as `a.pp_close {display:none}` -- it depends on if you want all prettyPhoto windows to hide the close button or not.